# How To Align Multiple Elements in the Same Div with CSS

Tags: css, alignment

I'm trying to align 4 elements horizontally in one div with little luck.

I've tried `inline-block`, `float left` with `margin-rights` to the elements but nothing is aligning and could use some help.

My elements:

```
return(
   <div className="counter">
       <p className="quantity">quantity: </p>
       <button className="counter-btn" id="decrease" onClick={this.decrementCount}>-</button>
       <p classname="count">{this.state.count}</p>
       <button className="counter-btn" id="increase" onClick={this.incrementCount}>+</button>
   </div>
  )
```

My CSS:

```
.counter {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px grey solid;
  width: 300px;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.counter-btn {
  background-color: lightslategrey;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
}

.quantity {
  float:left;
  padding-right: 2em;
}
.decrease {
  /* float:left; */
}
.count {
  /* float: left; */
}
```

This is how it's supposed to look:
[image: correct-way]

This is how it currently looks:
[image: current-way]

Could I please get help with the alignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex can help you with this one:

```
.counter {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close:

```
.counter {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px grey solid;
  width: 19em;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  text-align: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.counter-btn {
  background-color: lightslategrey;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

.quantity {
  float:left;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
.count {
  display: inline-block;
}
```